# Converting 2 variables (obtained by ICA decomposition) named A_ffdiag and W_ffdiag into mixing/unmixing matrix

Tags: signal-analysis, matrix, eeg, ica

I have two variables as a result of an ICA (Independent Component analysis) decomposition (decomposed using joint diagonalization algorithm which uses frobenius norm formulation) named A_ffdiag and W_ffdiag of shapes A_ffdiag : (116, 30) ,W_ffdiag : (30, 116) (where 30 is the number of components and 116 is the number od channels).

Now, I believe that  some operations need to me made on these two variables to convert them to mixing/unmixing matrix and further use them as ICA instance in MNE(python library). Can somebody help me in solving how can I convert these two variables into mixing/unmixing matrix?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit for us?

Comment: How are you calculating A_ffdiag and W_ffdiag? Are they outputs from some software package run on your data? What package? Have you checked the documentation of the function that gave you these outputs? My *guess* would be they are the mixing and  unmixing matrices, respectively. But it's hard to tell because your question is vague.